# I am Getting java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animation name: cn.pedant.SweetAlert.Rotate3dAnimation error:null

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-volley, sweetalert

My android app crashes when i try to logic in on press of the login button. I have tried to catch/handle the error but its still same result

I have tried but failed to catch the error so the app doesnt break

```
Response.ErrorListener() {
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
showMe.dismiss();
new SweetAlertDialog(LoginActivity.this, SweetAlertDialog.CUSTOM_IMAGE_TYPE)
.setTitleText("Network Error!")
.setContentText("Please Check Your Network Connection and Try Again")
.setCustomImage(R.drawable.ic_wifi)
.show();
}
});
```